# Java Client/Server - Can we make server as client to another server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I am looking on the website for my problem but seems I am not able to find out the solution yet. I have Java non-blocking client server program which works good. I took the example from [here](http://kramasundar.blogspot.com/2009/06/java-supports-nonblocking-io-since-java.html)

my problem is, how can I make the server as the client to another server as well? Right now, my server will has 2 listening ports to wait connection request from the client and that is achieved. Now, I want to make the server in the same time can connect to another server using different port. I have no idea how can I achieve this. Hope somebody could give some ideas. Big thank you guys!

Comment: Did you try multi-threading, I mean start a thread that has a client code and that would connect to some other server?

Comment: Just create another thread having client code. Thats it.

Comment: @Sudhanshu I am using nio which allows me to make less thread.

Comment: @SuKu where should I put it? Anywhere?

Comment: Use JMS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service

Comment: It depends , start a new thread where you want to access the other sever.

Comment: In that case just execute the client code, that's it.

Comment: @ZEROMILE thanks, appreciate it. I am very new to this thing. I hope that I could expand the codes which I put the link in my question.

Comment: @Sudhanshu, SuKu, thanks. just execute the client codes anywhere in server codes, my understanding is correct right?

Comment: @Sudhanshu, How can I put the multi-threading in Java NIO codes?

Answer (score 1):

Run a client towards another server from your server's code. As simple as that. What have you tried and was not able to accomplish in this scene? You might want to use Apache HTTP (there is synchronous and asynchronous version of it) client or [Netty](http://netty.io/) Asynchronous HTTP Client for this. Apache http client tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html)

Comment: right now, I don't know where I should put client codes inside my server codes. Can I put it anywhere?

Comment: added the link to tutorial - please check.

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate it. Seems like I can execute client codes in my server code anywhere which I find suitable right?

Comment: I want to put client codes in my serverA codes. However there will be 2 while loop, for the client block and server block as well. My problem is, if codes to connect to the serverB is running, my client cannot connect to serverA. How to solve this issue? create new object in serverA codes and do the connection to serverB in different class?

Answer (score 0):

I think a proxy should sort you out. More [here](http://www.dwgold.com/Projects/Networking/Proxyserver/Default.aspx)

Comment: appreciate it,thanks. Seems like what I have before. Now I have a bit different architecture. But the idea looks same, connect to another server when it is time to do it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The proxy server sits and waits, listening to a particular port on the local machine where it is running. Once a request is made to that port, the proxy then establishes a connection to a specified port on a specified remote host.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put client code into a server. Just like you could download an HTML page from within a Java Servlet.

Your server should have a "handler" component that processes incoming requests from your client. Inside this handler code, you can put your client code which connects to a different server.

I guess what confuses you is, that the incoming connection and the outgoing connection are now both handled in the same poll-the-selector loop, or? You can attach objects to the selector key, as far as I remember. Use that to signal that this is not an incoming connection, but an outgoing connection, and handle all outgoing connections differently from incoming connections. You may even have to connect these incoming and outgoing connections somehow, so you know which outgoing connection matches which incoming connections.